# Jmeter illegal reflective access operation error on linux command line

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jmeter

Installed

```
JMeter 5.1.1 
UBUNTU 19.10
Linux version 5.3.0.40
Java JDK 11.0.6 //also tried versions 8 & 9
```

Created a test plan with a JSR223 Sampler

Runs as expected in GUI mode , however when attempting to run via the command line a warning error stating An illegal reflective access operation has occurred.

I have tried adding the plug ins manager and updating plug ins 
Given access to the JAR files 
Note this works as expected when running in windows cmd

The error details:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields 
(file:/usr/share/java/xstream.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator


WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.

Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/lx-usr/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/templates/[testplan].jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 

---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException

cause-message       : 

first-jmeter-class
:org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)

class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper

required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper

converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter

path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[4]/hashTree/JSR223Sampler

line number         : 79

version             : 2.13.20180731
```

Comment: I think while running from command line, JMeter version 2.13 is picked. Please check whether you are running JMeter  5.1.1 from command line.

Comment: thanks for the reply .
jmeter 5.1.1 is referenced in the statement on the command line but it's still throwing the error.

Comment: the jmeter version was indeed incorrect! Linux installed version 2.13 which then overrides the new version when running on command line
The updated version is now added and the plugins have been installed via the plugin manager . all good. Thanks

Comment: Good to know its working now. Cheers.

Comment: @DelPatel I am facing similar issue now. How did you resolve this issue? Could you please elaborate